# Netlify build error for a Hugo site - how to fix?

Tags: hugo, netlify

The following error is returned when attempting to render a Hugo-based website via Netlify:

```
1:39:23 PM: ERROR 2019/09/21 17:39:23 Unable to load gallery in /opt/build/repo/content/home/gallery/index.md.
```

The entire log is [here](https://app.netlify.com/sites/focused-ritchie-e82ae1/deploys/5d8660386da4e1683fab0e43).

The source for the website that I am trying to deploy is [here](https://github.com/making-data-science-count/homepage).

I've searched a number of websites for this error or what other issue it may signify, but haven't been successful in understanding why this error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `netlify.toml` on the root beside `config.toml` and retry. `netlify.toml` content should be like this:

```
[build]
publish = "public"
command = "hugo"

[context.production.environment]
HUGO_VERSION = "0.69.2"
HUGO_ENV = "production"
HUGO_ENABLEGITINFO = "true"
```